# Guard Rails 4 - uninitialized constant Listen::Turnstile (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble with `gem 'guard'`... below is my gemfile.

the full error is:

```
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/guard-1.4.0/lib/guard.rb:47:in `setup': uninitialized constant Listen::Turnstile (NameError)
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/guard-1.4.0/lib/guard.rb:155:in `start'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/guard-1.4.0/lib/guard/cli.rb:104:in `start'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/guard-1.4.0/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/guard:23:in `load'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

How did you get guard and its dependencies to work with rails4?

```
  source 'http://rubygems.org'

  gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'sendgrid'
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'simple_form'

  #assets
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'jquery-rails'

  gem 'simple_form'

  gem 'omniauth'
  gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
  gem 'koala', '~> 1.7.0rc1'

  gem 'figaro'

  #deployment
  gem 'rubber', :git => 'https://github.com/rubber/rubber.git', :branch => 'master'
  gem 'therubyracer', :group => :assets

  #server
  gem 'unicorn'

  #photo processing and connecting to S3
  gem 'mini_magick', '~> 3.6.0'
  gem 'carrierwave'
  gem 'fog'

  group :test, :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'shoulda-matchers'
    gem 'pry'
  end

  group :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
  end

  group :test do
    #fake data for testing
    gem 'faker'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2'

    gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 0.9'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'capybara-webkit', '~> 0.14'

    gem 'guard'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'rb-fsevent'
  end
  gem 'open4'
```

Comment: Do you need `gem 'guard'`?  I run guard with rspec and only need `gem 'guard-rspec`

Answer (score 1):

This may help you out, there is a dependency issue with better errors https://github.com/danbartlett/opensit/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify `guard` version in your `Gemfile` using `gem 'guard', '~> 2.1.1'`